# Remove space outside quotes marks comma in txt file

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a txt file that I need to insert data from that file.
I am getting the file from a folder and put in another folder before isnerting into SQL. I need to remove all spaces before storing in the folder. I am using this c# code:

```
// Upload files
                    TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
                    transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

                    TransferOperationResult transferResult;
                    //transferResult = session.PutFiles(FileSource + FileName, FileDestination, false, transferOptions);
                    transferResult = session.GetFiles(FileSource + FileNameSource, FileDestination + FileNameDestination, false, transferOptions);
                    // Throw on any error
                    transferResult.Check();
```

The format of files is separated by comma but with quotes marks like this:
[image]
However this file has a lof of spaces after last column. I need to remove that spaces.
Does anyone know how can I remove that space:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to read a line from a file? Try to devide your problem into smaller chunks: reading a file. Iterating its lines. Do something with the line. Modifiy it. Write the content back to the file. Where *specifically* do you need help here?

Comment: I am trying to insert the data into SQL database and I am getting an error due to these spaces. I just need to remove them.

Comment: Read the file with IO.File.ReadAllLines and iterate on each line with TrimEnd. Please include some code on how you are reading the file.

Comment: @Jazz. I have updated with code.

Comment: I am not sure if the text file that you are showing is the source or the destination. I will consider it to be the source. If so, you need to do the following before running your code: Read the file, remove the blanks, save the file. Then run the TransferCode methods. You can use the method of my previous comment or the one from @Yul's answer.

Comment: @Jazz. I need to read the file and save the file phisically or I can create a variavle that store the file without the spaces and use this variable to send to second folder?

Comment: I am not familiar with that Transfer methods. I do not know that namespace/methods, but from the signature that you presented, you need to save the file. See if there are other overloads where you can pass the text variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

If i got your problem here you are :

```
    fileContents = fileContents.Replace(" ", "");
```

Then you can put the modified text back to the file. Otherwise:

```
fileContents = fileContents.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```